# How can I print a 5x5 room grid using a 2D array?

Tags: java

I need to create a 5X5 grid of rooms that has 5 rows and 5 columns with a 2d Array.

I have the square rooms created in a toString but every time I try to print it with a nested for loop I get a vertical display of rooms.

```java
public String toString() {
  if(roomNumberX ==0 && roomNumberY==0) {
    return"* * *\n* "+item+" |"+"\n* - *";

  } else if(roomNumberX==4 && roomNumberY==0) {
    return "* * * "+"\n| "+item+" *"+"\n* - *";

  } else if(roomNumberX==4 && roomNumberY==4) {
    return "* - * \n| " +item+" *"+"\n* * *";

  } else if(roomNumberX==0 && roomNumberY==4) {
    return "* - *"+"\n* "+item+" |"+"\n* * *";

  } else if(roomNumberX==0 && roomNumberY !=0 || roomNumberY !=4) {
    return "* - *"+"\n* "+item+" |"+"\n* - *";

  } else if(roomNumberX==4 && roomNumberY !=0 || roomNumberY !=4) {
    return "* - *"+"\n| "+item+ " *"+" \n* - *";

  } else if(roomNumberY==0 && roomNumberX != 0 && roomNumberX !=4) {
    return "* * *"+"\n| "+item+" |"+"\n* - *";

  } else if(roomNumberY==4 && roomNumberX !=0 && roomNumberX != 4) {
    return "* - *"+"\n| "+item+" |"+"\n* * *";

  }
  return "* - *\n| "+item+" |\n* - *";
}
```

Below is my attempt at the nested for loop

```java
public void lookAtMap() {
  for(int i=0; i<room.length; i++) {
    for(int x=0; x<room[i].length;x++) {
      System.out.print(room[i][x]);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
* - ** - *
* P |
* - ** - *
| P |
* * *
* * * 
| P *
* - ** - *
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A 5X5 grid of squares where each row is 4 squares horizantally stacked ontop of each other and 4 columns.

Comment: Maybe add that as an example to your question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your nested for loops look great for traversing a 2D array.  That `toString()`, though, what the heck is going on in there?  How are `roomNumberX` and `roomNumberY` getting changed?  Not by the loop.  Show more code so we might be able to understand what's going on...

Comment: The toString is a series of rooms with * * * being borders of the 2d array grid and * - * being anywhere that isn't a border

Comment: But why are you storing MORE THAN ONE ROOM in one "thing"?  Normally you'd store an OBJECT in each slot of the 2D array, with each instance of something representing only ONE room.  I'm certain I'm not the only one that is extremely confused by your code.  Can you post more of your code along with any requirements/instructions that were given to you?  As it is, no one is going to be able to provide much help...